# What is the difference between load name and load global in python bytecode?

Tags: python, bytecode, python-internals

load name takes its argument and pushes onto the stack the  value of the name stored by store name at the position indicated by the argument .  load global does something similar, but there appears to be no store global in the bytecode. So what is the difference and how  does load global work

Answer (score 7):

The difference between `LOAD_NAME` and `LOAD_GLOBAL` is where they search for a given `name`.

### `LOAD_NAME`

When Python encounters a `LOAD_NAME` opcode:

- It first searches in `f_locals` - the names local to the current frame object.
- If it doesn't find the given name in `f_locals`, it then proceeds to search in `f_globals` - the global names of the frame object. These are the names in the surrounding scope of the frame object.
- If doesn't find the name in `f_globals`, it then searches `f_builtins`. `f_builtins` is a dictionary of the builtin names Python uses.
- If all of the above fails, Python raises a `NameError`.

Here the relevant C code where the virtual machine executes a `LOAD_NAME` instruction:

```c
    TARGET(LOAD_NAME) {
        PyObject *name = GETITEM(names, oparg);
        PyObject *locals = f->f_locals;
        PyObject *v;
        if (locals == NULL) {
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_SystemError,
                         "no locals when loading %R", name);
            goto error;
        }
        if (PyDict_CheckExact(locals)) {
            v = PyDict_GetItem(locals, name);
            Py_XINCREF(v);
        }
        else {
            v = PyObject_GetItem(locals, name);
            if (v == NULL) {
                if (!PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_KeyError))
                    goto error;
                PyErr_Clear();
            }
        }
        if (v == NULL) {
            v = PyDict_GetItem(f->f_globals, name);
            Py_XINCREF(v);
            if (v == NULL) {
                if (PyDict_CheckExact(f->f_builtins)) {
                    v = PyDict_GetItem(f->f_builtins, name);
                    if (v == NULL) {
                        format_exc_check_arg(
                                    PyExc_NameError,
                                    NAME_ERROR_MSG, name);
                        goto error;
                    }
                    Py_INCREF(v);
                }
                else {
                    v = PyObject_GetItem(f->f_builtins, name);
                    if (v == NULL) {
                        if (PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_KeyError))
                            format_exc_check_arg(
                                        PyExc_NameError,
                                        NAME_ERROR_MSG, name);
                        goto error;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        PUSH(v);
        DISPATCH();
    }
```

### `LOAD_GLOBAL`

When Python encounters a `LOAD_GLOBAL` opcode:

- Python first searches for the name in `f_globals` - the names in surrounding scopes that the current frame object references.
- If doesn't find the name in `f_globals`, it then searches `f_builtins`. `f_builtins` is a dictionary of the builtin names Python uses.
- If all of the above fails, Python raises a `NameError`.

Here the relevant C code where the virtual machine executes a `LOAD_GLOBAL` instruction:

```c
    TARGET(LOAD_GLOBAL) {
        PyObject *name = GETITEM(names, oparg);
        PyObject *v;
        if (PyDict_CheckExact(f->f_globals)
            && PyDict_CheckExact(f->f_builtins))
        {
            v = _PyDict_LoadGlobal((PyDictObject *)f->f_globals,
                                   (PyDictObject *)f->f_builtins,
                                   name);
            if (v == NULL) {
                if (!_PyErr_OCCURRED()) {
                    /* _PyDict_LoadGlobal() returns NULL without raising
                     * an exception if the key doesn't exist */
                    format_exc_check_arg(PyExc_NameError,
                                         NAME_ERROR_MSG, name);
                }
                goto error;
            }
            Py_INCREF(v);
        }
        else {
            /* Slow-path if globals or builtins is not a dict */

            /* namespace 1: globals */
            v = PyObject_GetItem(f->f_globals, name);
            if (v == NULL) {
                if (!PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_KeyError))
                    goto error;
                PyErr_Clear();

                /* namespace 2: builtins */
                v = PyObject_GetItem(f->f_builtins, name);
                if (v == NULL) {
                    if (PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_KeyError))
                        format_exc_check_arg(
                                    PyExc_NameError,
                                    NAME_ERROR_MSG, name);
                    goto error;
                }
            }
        }
        PUSH(v);
        DISPATCH();
    }
```

### So, what's the difference?

As you could probably see, the difference is that `LOAD_GLOBAL` skips straight to searching the global names of the frame object, whereas `LOAD_NAME` starts searching the local names and makes it way up. The `LOAD_GLOBAL` opcode is useful for the case where Python already knows that a name cannot be local, so it skips searching local names altogether.

**Note:** if your looking to learn more about how the Python virtual machine works, I looking over [Byterun](https://github.com/nedbat/byterun/blob/master/byterun/pyvm2.py), a pure-python implementation of the CPython virtual machine. It also has an [accompanying article](http://www.aosabook.org/en/500L/a-python-interpreter-written-in-python.html) by Allison Kaptur.

Comment: please re check the question? "load name" not "load fast" ... "load name and load global"

Comment: @SreerajTA Thanks for the heads up. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is a `STORE_GLOBAL`. Trigger it by using the `global` directive and assigning to that name:

```
def foo():
    global a 
    a = 3

dis(foo)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              2 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (a)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

`LOAD_GLOBAL`/`STORE_GLOBAL` are, afaik, instructions that mostly make sense when `locals() != globals()` and Python knows (by using a SymbolTable during compilation) that it needs to skip the locals dict altogether. This is something that is true inside functions.

In the top level scope, `locals() == globals()` so the compiler follows the normal look-up rule by using `LOAD_NAME` (unless you directly use `global`, see `dis('global b; b = 40')`).