# Why can't I call a function from another function using exec

Tags: python

say, I have very simple piece of code

```py
py = """
a = 1
print (f'before all {a=}')

def bar(n):
    print(f'bye {n=}')

def foo(n):
    print(f'hello {n=}')
    bar(n)

bar ('just works')    
foo ('sara')
"""

loc = {}
glo = {}
bytecode = compile(py, "script", "exec")
exec(bytecode, glo, loc)
```

as you can see I defined two functions: `bar` & `foo` and called both of them with results:

```
before all a=1
bye n='just works'
hello n='sara'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bla-bla/pythonProject/main_deco2.py", line 43, in <module>
    exec(bytecode, glo, loc)
  File "script", line 13, in <module>
  File "script", line 10, in foo
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

and this leaves me puzzled, as I don't understand why function `foo` doesn't see `bar` when just a second ago I was able to call `bar` without a problem ?

Comment: As a lead: if you skip the `foo` parts in the code, and examine the dicts afterwards, you will find that `a` and `bar` end up in the locals dict, not the globals dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> If exec gets two separate objects as *globals* and *locals*, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition.

That's not what you want, so don't provide a *locals*.

```
glo = {}
exec(bytecode, glo)
```

Output, for reference:

```
before all a=1
bye n='just works'
hello n='sara'
bye n='sara'
```

Comment: P.S. I haven't quite wrapped my head around *why* it's treated as if it were in a class definition, so if anyone could explain it, I'm all ears. I do understand that class scope is kinda weird though, so it's probably related to that.

Answer (score 1):

An important diagnostic:

```
>>> dis.dis(bytecode)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (a)

  3           4 LOAD_NAME                1 (print)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('before all a=')
              8 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             10 FORMAT_VALUE             2 (repr)
             12 BUILD_STRING             2
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 POP_TOP
```

I omitted most of the result, but the first few lines show what is going on. Accesses to `a` and `bar` use the `LOAD_NAME` and `STORE_NAME` opcodes, which [use the locals first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773382). (It cannot use `LOAD_FAST` because it is not a compiled function.) To work around this, simply mark the necessary names as `global` explicitly.

Unfortunately, I don't have a good answer for why it does this.